# I can't upload multiple large files

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku, serialization, celery

I am developing an application with Django, AWS S3 and hosted on Heroku.

At one point users have to upload multiple large files, totaling around 150MB each time.
I have tried various approaches.

1st attempt: directly call the save method of the Django form:
Result: the request takes more than 30 seconds and returns a timeout.

2nd attempt: temporarily save the file to a Heroku directory and read it from Celery task.
Result: Cannot save because it throws FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on production.

3rd attempt: pass the uploaded files (in memory files) to a celery task but the bytes cannot be serialized and passed to the task neither with json or with pickle.

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be like that

1. Expose an APIs to generate presigned URL for Frontend ([Steps are here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)).
2. Upload files by using that URL from the frontend in async way. That will offload your computation at Backend.
3. After successful upload, you will get an URL of file location. Now save the S3 URL along with other fields data to Django model.

You can upload more than 150MB file size by this method. Your system will be scalable.